# Working with List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two list : (Note: List's Items are combination of "NAME" & "ID" )

```
List<string> ListA = new List() {"SAM001","SAM002","SAM003","PIT001","PIT002","PIT004","ROSE001","ROSE002","JASE001" };
//so on

List<string> ListB = new List() {"SAM001","SAM003","PIT000","ROSE002","JASE001","INDI000"};` 
//so on...
```

Now Based on these two list i want to create two new list suppose listCommon & listUncommon.

listCommon will contain all matched items of ListA & ListB.

listUnCommon will contain all remaining items of ListA

**Now My condition is if Any item in ListB has NAME + 000 then all the items of ListA starting with that Name should add in my listCommon.**

Example 1 : if ListB item is PIT000 and ListA item are PIT001,PIT002,PIT003,ABC001
then listCommon = PIT001,PIT002,PIT003 because ListB has PIT with 000 so condition true all ListA 'PIT' items added in listcommon

So as above list and my condition i want my final list below

```
List<string> listCommon = new List() {"SAM001","SAM003", "PIT001","PIT002","PIT004","ROSE002", "JASE001" };
List<string> listUncommon = new List() {"SAM002", "ROSE001"};
```

Please suggest..i just spend my couple of minutes in loops but not getting actual result as i mentioned :(

Comment: What have you tried? What results are you getting?  How do they differ from your desired result?

Comment: `i just spend my couple of minutes in loops but not getting actual result as i mentioned :(` So you'r couple of minutes are more valuable then ours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
var common = ListA.Intersect(ListB)
    .Concat(
        ListA.Where(a => 
             ListB.Any(
                b => b.EndsWith("000") && 
                b.StartsWith(a.Substring(0, a.Length - 3))
             )
        )
    );
var uncommon = ListA.Except(common);
```

Using an insersect, then you are selecting any from list A where list B has an entry that matches the first 3 letters and ends with 000.

This is not the most efficient way of doing this, however it is terse code-wise.

Comment: One-liner statement doesn't have to be one line.

Comment: Valid. It's a mess even when split out, though :)

Comment: Hey Thanks...i am quite happy with these lines and also for your quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the common items from 2 lists:

`var listCommon = list1.Intersect(list`2);

Updated - Subtracted items:

```
var subtractedItems = new HashSet(listCommon);
commonItems.ExceptWith(list1);
```

Comment: Have you seen Austins's answer?

Comment: yeah sorry understood it wrongly. i think you are looking for subtraction.. am i right? i have updated

Comment: Vinoth, this does not answer his question.

Comment: vinoth just check smdrager's solution...